# Books Authored by P.S. Modenov

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, geometry, book-recommendation

Does anyone have any digital copies of the English translated versions of the books written by Soviet mathematician, Peter S. Modenov?

Answer (score 0):

All the English e-books by Modenov are available [here](http://libgen.org/search.php?req=Modenov&open=0&view=simple&phrase=1&column=def).

Comment: I don't think these are legal copies.

Comment: @Michael, as you can see on the libgen.org webpage given by me, it shows year of publication as 1965. In my view, the copyright doesn't hold for books which are 50 years older or more. I have searched the Elsevier website for author "Modenov" at http://www.elsevier.com/s/search.html?query=modenov&collection=elsevier-meta&advanced=true&form=sitesearch&profile=_default&publicationtitle=&afterdate=Any&beforedate=Any&author=modenov&isbn=  but I couldn't find any book. So, the book is out of print and I think it would be legal